# how to make file endpoint in mule configerable

Tags: mule

I have a flow with file endpoint and groovy.

I want to make the file path configerable.
Please suggest.

I am using file node to trigger the flow. So if anybody can suggest me that how to trigger groovy alone then there will be no need to use file endpoint.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Please edit your Q and add what you have tried

Comment: I am working in Mule. My task was to take a file from a location and using some command, send the records inside the file in to one database. So, what i did is put a file node to take the file and write sone code in groovy to execute the command on that file. But, i want to make the file path configurable so that in future, if file path location get change, then i just change in file.properties file.

Comment: i have already used <spring:beans>
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:file.properties" />
    </spring:beans>            but I am getting error ::  Could not resolve placeholder 'file.CATName' in string value "${file.CATName}"

Comment: Add your configuration file to the question.

Comment: <wmq:connector name="WMQ" hostName="${wmq.hostname}" port="${wmq.port}" queueManager="${wmq.queue.manager}"validateConnections="true" doc:name="WMQ"/>    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="property-placeholder1" name="Bean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <spring:property name="location" value="classpath:wmq.properties"/>             
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>   
    <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do here is configure a file endpoint like so and use this as your inbound endpoint to trigger the flow:

```
<file:endpoint name="inputFile" path="${input.path}"> 
   <!-- Add any filters (e.g. regex) here -->        
</file:endpoint>
```

Then, you should create a mule-app.properties file inside of src/main/resources that will include something like the following:

```
# Input Properties
input.path=/path/to/file
```

Lastly, include the following at the top of your Mule config file (after `<mule>` but **before** your flow):

```
<spring:beans>
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mule-app.properties" />
</spring:beans>
```

Doing this should allow you to achieve what you've outlined above. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting the same error. I actual, I have one more bean defines as        <wmq:connector name="WMQ" hostName="${wmq.hostname}" port="${wmq.port}" queueManager="${wmq.queue.manager}" username="${wmq.username}" password="${wmq.password}" validateConnections="true" doc:name="WMQ"/>
 
  
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="property-placeholder1" name="Bean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <spring:property name="location" value="classpath:wmq.properties"/>             
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>

Comment: Try combining all of your properties into one properties file, e.g. `mule-app.properties`, and have one spring bean as I've outlined above. If you need to override certain properties in different environments, you can create a properties override file as outlined [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Parameters+in+Your+Configuration+Files). I think the issue you're having here is that you're configuring multiple properties files and they are conflicting. So try placing all of your properties in one, as described - that should work.

Comment: Good to hear, can you please accept the answer so that the question isn't left open. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, But could you please tell me where to accept the answer